# Xamarin.Forms CarouselView CurrentItem binding not working in v4.6.0.772

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a carouselview and a button. I want when user clicks the button carousel changes CurrentItem.
Here is my xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <CarouselView CurrentItem="{Binding Answer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Display}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <Button Text="Next" Command="{Binding OnNext}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And here is my viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Answer> _answers;
    private Answer _answer;
    private int _index = 0;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>()
        {
            new Answer("Ans1"),
            new Answer("Ans2"),
            new Answer("Ans3"),
        };
        Answer = Answers[_index];
        OnNext = new Command(() =>
        {
            _index++;
            Answer = Answers[_index];
        });
    }

    public List<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return _answers; }
        set
        {
            if (_answers != value)
            {
                _answers = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Answers)));
            }
        }
    }

    public Answer Answer
    {
        get { return _answer; }
        set
        {
            if (_answer != value)
            {
                _answer = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Answer)));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ICommand OnNext { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I set binding context:

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
```

"Answer" is simple class with one string property Display

This code completly works in xamarin.forms 4.4.0.991265, but when I updated XF to 4.6.0.772 it stoped change CurrentItem and carousel doesn't move when I press the button "Next".

The same picture with Position binding. It works in 4.4.0.991265, but not in 4.6.0.772 when I increment position in view model.

I tried it on android emulator: Android 9.0 - API 28

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in `4.7.0.772` and `4.7.0.773-pre`. The workaround now is using a earlier version like Xamarin.forms `4.6.0.726`. You can open an issue in Github to report this problem.

Comment: I love the way XF goes backwards to go forwards!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public ObservableCollection<Answer> _answers { get; set; }
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @goro, the answer does not provide clarity. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.